# ajax, how to change two divs using one ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

how to change 2 divs using one ajax request ?

ajax-update.php

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php");
include("user.inc.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$item = New item($id);
$result = $item->iteminfo;
echo $result->name."<br />";
unset($item); 
?>
```

**html:**

```
<tr>
<td> (one) </td>

<td><input type="text" value="" onchange="showUser<?php echo $x;?>(this.value)"  style="width:70px;"/></td>

<td><span id="txtHint<?php echo $x;?>"></span></td>

<td><input type="text" value="" name="price_<?php echo $x;?>" id="price_<?php echo $x;?>"  onchange="upperCase<?php echo $x+$h;?>()" style="width:40px;"/></td>

<td><input type="text"  id="proce_<?php echo $x;?>" style="width:70px;" value="<?php echo $x+$h;?>" disabled /></td>

<td><input type="text" value="" name="price_<?php echo $x;?>"   style="width:40px;"/></td>

<td><input type='text' id="totalPrice<?php echo $x;?>" disabled /></td>

</tr>
```

**script:**

```
function showUser<?php echo $x;?>(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint<?php echo $x;?>").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint<?php echo $x;?>").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax-update.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

my question is, when i change this value

```
<td><input type="text" value="" onchange="showUser<?php echo $x;?>(this.value)"  style="width:70px;"/></td>
```

not only this td

```
<td><span id="txtHint<?php echo $x;?>"></span></td>
```

but also this td

```
    <td><input type="text"  id="proce_<?php echo $x;?>" style="width:70px;" value="<?php echo $x+$h;?>" disabled /></td>
```

now i only can change one div (txtHint) on the fly,

sory for my english.

note :
i want to put un update with diferent file,
for example when value change, this script is word

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax-update.php?id="+str,true);
```

and the other one is

```
foo.php
```

thanks

angga

EDIT 1:

[1] | [2] | [3]

- [1] : i input value manualy
- [2] : this span txtHint change using ajax
- [3] : i want this change too same as [2]

EDIT 2 :

```
document.getElementById("txtHint<?php echo $x;?>").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("proce_<?php echo $x;?>").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

thats is work,
but value in [2] and [3] is same, because it take from one file ajax-update.php
how to add other file but still in one ajax request ?

Comment: In first sentence of your question you say you want to change divs, but you are actually only talking about the td elements mentioned at the end of your question, right?

Comment: yap. td is just for cover, i want to put other div inside the td.
sory if my question or my english is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the text for the first element (a SPAN) as well as the second (an INPUT).

The span you seem to have figured out -- you use innerHTML. You wrote:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint<?php echo $x;?>").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Underneath that... you could add

```
document.getElementById("proce_<?php echo $x;?>").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

However -- you should also look into using jQuery for this kind of thing. It takes care of the cross-browser stuff for you, and makes this kind of coding MUCH simpler. You can do all the JSON/XML requests you want, and update individual components easily.

Comment: You are using (like in the question, however) PHP code in the getElementById function. That string parameter should be changed to the actual id outputted by the PHP code.

Comment: thanks, it change, but the result is same with span, how to add other file like this xmlhttp.open("GET","other-ajax.php?id="+str,true);
where to put it ?

Comment: @AnggaMovic If you want to get information from another page, then you have to make TWO xmlhttp requests. So what you could do is either create a second, separate xmlhttp request -- so xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); becomes xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest(); and xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();  ... or you can create a new function that will handle each xmlhttp request url (as the first function argument) and you can specify the element which should be changed when the result comes back (as the second function argument).

Comment: @jo jo thanks,  xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest(); its work, now i can change 2 or more div by adding that. thanks a lot :)

Comment: it fist changes value of 1 div then in the second call it changes value of other div